# Figuring out syntax of a special notation

Tags: c++

Hello I would like to figure out what does this mean and what is this notation?

```
fakecalss f1("getName", Type::STRING, AC::PUBLIC);
```

I know it is invoking the constructor of fake class, but what does Type::STRING mean? How is this implemented?

Comment: Well, we don't know what `Type` is. It's defined somewhere in the code, which you haven't shown us. Once you've found `Type`, you can find the nested declaration for `STRING`.

Comment: Could it be enum class types probably? I have something similar in one of my codes.

Comment: Rightclick on fakeclass, select go to declaration, paste the code here.

Answer (score 2):

`Type` and `AC` are any named scopes (without seeing the declaration of them, it is not possible to say more about it; each might be a namespace, a class type or an enum class, or maybe a typedef to a type with associated scope). `STRING` is a name (probably of a constant) in the scope named `Type`, and `PUBLIC` is a name (probably of a constant) in the scope named `AC`.

All this is, of course, under the assumption that none of those are macros.

A few possibilities which all would make `Type::STRING` legal code (with differing semantics, for illustrative purposes I also add another value `Type::INTEGER`):

- A normal constant in a namespace:

  ```
  namespace Type
  {
    int const STRING = 0;
    int const INTEGER = 1;
  }
  ```
- A normal enum in s namespace:

  ```
  namespace Type
  {
    enum foo { STRING, INTEGER };
  }
  ```
- A static constant in a struct:

  ```
  struct Type
  {
    static int const STRING = 0;
    static int const INTEGER = 1;
  };
  ```
- A normal enum in a struct:

  ```
  struct Type
  {
    enum { STRING, INTEGER };
  };
  ```
- C++11 and later only: An enum class:

  ```
  enum class Type { STRING, INTEGER };
  ```

Note that this list is in no way exhaustive.

Comment: Hello I would like to know more about how to creat name constant pleas. The thing is I have to creat a code that will allow this to work. Therefore as you see I have the same confussion.

Comment: Thank you alot. I know want to know how to store objets without using arrays, vectors or lists. If that is possible.